# Handling extra rows in colMeans calculations

Tags: r

I'm an occasional R-user working with several large annual datasets with one column for year and another for the location, similar to the following (which I'll call "timeseries"):

```
Year    L1     
1960   1.11   
1961   1.14   
1962   0.75   
1963   0.63   
1964   1.15   
1965   1.08   
1966   1.69   
1967   0.77    
1968   0.69
```

I'm trying to calculate `colMeans` by groups of 4, but the number of rows in my datasets is not always evenly divisible by 4. Ideally, I would any extra rows to be included in the calculation for the previous group.

So in the example above with 9 rows, R would calculate the average for `1960-1963` (a group of 4), `1964-1968` (a group of 5).

Is this possible?

My current code for groups of 4 is below:

```
fouryrave <- rep(colMeans(matrix(timeseries$L1, nrow=4), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Are you intent on using colMeans, as it may be easier to creating a grouping variables and then use aggregate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create a grouping variable and aggregate, i.e.

```
n = 4
l1 <- nrow(df) %/% n
df$grp <- c(rep(seq(l1), each = n), rep(tail(seq(l1), 1), nrow(df) - n * l1))

aggregate(L1 ~ grp, df, mean)
#  grp     L1
#1   1 0.9075
#2   2 1.0760
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Year = 1960:1968, L1 = c(1.11, 1.14, 0.75, 0.63, 
1.15, 1.08, 1.69, 0.77, 0.69)), .Names = c("Year", "L1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment (and I had some time to kill), here is a function that accepts a `type` argument which specifies the method of grouping,

```
f1 <- function(df, n, type = 1){
  if(type == 1){
    l1 <- nrow(df) %/% n
    df$grp <- c(rep(seq(l1), each = n), rep(tail(seq(l1), 1), nrow(df) - n * l1))
    return(aggregate(L1 ~ grp, df, mean)) 
  } else {
  if(type == 2){
    l1 <- nrow(df) %/% n
    df$grp <- c(rep(seq(l1), each = n), rep(tail(l1, 1)+1, nrow(df) - n * l1))
    return(aggregate(L1 ~ grp, df, mean))
    }
  }

}

f1(df, 4, type = 1)
#  grp     L1
#1   1 0.9075
#2   2 1.0760

f1(df, 4, type = 2)
#  grp     L1
#1   1 0.9075
#2   2 1.1725
#3   3 0.6900
```

Comment: Thanks, that did what I needed.

Comment: One (probably silly) question-- can this same thing be used if I wanted the extra row(s) to be their own group?

Comment: I m not sure I understand your question. The above just assigns a value every n rows and if there are extra rows it asaigns them the same value as the last

Comment: Okay, so I'm going to have to go a different route when I want the extra groups to be assigned a new value.

Comment: @Sotos-- what a great function-- thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the mean of the last group separately from other ones like this:

```
fouryrave <- colMeans(matrix(timeseries$L1[1:((length(timeseries$L1) %/% 4 
                    -1)*4)],nrow=4),na.rm=TRUE)

fouryrave[length(fouryrave)+1] <- 
           mean(timeseries$L1[(((length(timeseries$L1)%/%4-1)*4)+1):length(timeseries$L1)])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually going to need this one, too, when I want to calculate last group separately.